# Create read more link in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create a link with read more text. if there are more than 3 lines in a paragraph this link should be visible and clicking on this it show display all the lines.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Can you show us your attempts to do this and what problems you are having? A jsFiddle would be great!!

Answer (score 12):

I wanted to do the same thing, so I created a directive. Have a look here: https://gist.github.com/doukasd/0744566c5494ebc8643f

Usage is pretty simple:

```
<p data-dd-collapse-text="100">{{veryLongText}}</p>
```

Where 100 is the character limit you want to specify.

**UPDATE:** [dd-text-collapse](https://github.com/doukasd/AngularJS-Components)

Comment: Can you please answer my question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26016709/ddcollapse-not-working-for-more-than-one-elements

Comment: Can we use this for line numbers instead of characters ? B'cos sometimes the last word is cutting off in middle.

Comment: Will need some new logic to know how many lines the text is. Don't know it off the top of my head but I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: Any thoughts on this adjustment?: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138942/finds-a-position-to-break-a-string-that-is-not-part-of-a-br

Answer (score 10):

For read more , you can use angular limitTo filter for limiting your paragraph to character's length instead of limiting paragraph to line numbers .

You can use something like this :

in html

```
<p> {{myString | limitTo:numLimit}} </p>
<button type='button' ng-click="readMore()">read more</button>
```

in controller

```
$scope.numLimit=200;
$scope.readMore=function(){
$scope.numLimit=10000;
};
```

Comment: Fatemeh, how would you account for html tags that you would not want rendered?

Comment: Nice solution. I only edited numLimit inside readMore function to be undefined as limitTo accepts undefined to return the string unchanged

Answer (score 8):

Based on some of the information here I've put together a nice show more/less implementation

Directive Definition
showMore.js

```
.directive('showMore', 
function(){
    return {
        templateUrl: 'showMore.html',
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        scope:{
            'showMoreHeight': '@'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$interval', function($scope, $element, $interval) {

            $scope.expanded = false;

            $interval(function(){
                renderStyles();
            }, 300);

            $scope.expandable = false;
            function renderStyles(){
                if($element.height() >= $scope.showMoreHeight && $scope.expanded === false){
                    $scope.expandable = true;
                }
            }

            $scope.showLessStyle = {
                'max-height': $scope.showMoreHeight + 'px',
                'overflow': 'hidden'
            };

        }]
    };
});
```

showMore.html

```
<span>
    <div ng-style='showLessStyle' ng-hide='expanded' ng-transclude>
    </div>
    <div ng-show='expanded' ng-transclude>
    </div>
    <a style='float:right;' ng-hide='expanded || !expandable' ng-click='expanded = !expanded' localize>show more</a>
    <a style='float:right;' ng-show='expanded && expandable' ng-click='expanded = !expanded'>show less</a>
</span>
```

The usage is fairly simple just transclude what ever you want to show more/less of

USEAGE:

```
<div show-more show-more-height='150'>
    <div class='showMoreContent'></div>
</div>
```

I hope this is somewhat helpful!

Comment: Thanks... first solution I've found that uses height instead of number of words/characters, which can be a bit vague!

Answer (score 5):

There can be some workaround.

basic idea is like this

```
 1. at first, use javascript to calculate the original height
 2. if higher than 3 lines , set the overflow to hidden and show a button. The button is used to toggle state
 3.  if not,  do nothing
```

---

About the button.

If the button is out of text area, it's no problem for you I think. 
If you need the button inline within the element, there are 2 possibilitis.

1. if you want it position fixed at right-bottom, 
         create a gradient background for the button, fade-out effect. 
         It looks nice and very simple.

   here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sunderls/HYHZ6/ . 
   **Everytime toggling the state, you actually change the class of the element.**
2. if you want it right after the end of text?  it's a little tricky, since even if text height is 3 lines, you cannot be sure
   whether it remains 3 lines height , after appending a button next to
   it.

   I think one way is to use Range API, to calculate the paragraph
   dimensions,  (I've used the api in my collamark.com, it's powerful
   but different browsers have different behaviors). Actually you can
   get the dimensions of every lines dynamically.  And by some
   backwards loops, you can get the appropriate substring of the text, 
   to show in collapsed mode, which is just right for 3 lines height
   with a button. (the api doc is here:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/range)

   So **now every time you toggle the state, you actually is change the
   text. not the class**.

### Here begins the Code when do it in Angular

## template

first, this kind of feature is a standalone module which you can reuse everywhere, so in your template, we create a new directive `autoFolded`, sth like this:

```
<auto-folded>
    <p>Some text here, maybe long maybe short</p>
</auto-folded>
```

## directive.coffee

then we handle all the logic in directive definition( sorry for writing in coffee though)

```
directive('autoFolded',[
 '$window'
($window) ->
    return {
        restrict: 'E'
        transclude: true
        template: '<div class="auto-folded"><div ng-transclude></div><a href ng-click="toggleFoldedState()" class="auto-folded--more"></a></div>'
        link: (scope, element, attrs)->
            $$window = $ $window
            content = $(element).find('.auto-folded')

            toggleFoldedState = ->
                if content.hasClass 'auto-folded--folded'
                    content.removeClass('auto-folded--folded').addClass('auto-folded--unfolded')
                else if content.hasClass 'auto-folded--unfolded'
                    content.removeClass('auto-folded--unfolded').addClass('auto-folded--folded')

                return

            scope.toggleFoldedState = toggleFoldedState


            init = ()->
                contentHeight = content.outerHeight()
                if contentHeight > 48
                    content.addClass 'auto-folded--folded'
                content.show()

            $$window.on 'ngcontentloaded',init

    }
])
```

#### here is the explaination

for this directive contains text it doesn't know, so it's a translucent direcitve. Like a modal popup, it contains the Text and a toggle button.

```
restrict: 'E'
transclude: true
template: '<div class="auto-folded"><div ng-transclude></div><a href ng-click="toggleFoldedState()" class="auto-folded--more"></a></div>'
```

when clicking the button, it actually do the toggling. If unfolded, then fold it; If foled, then unfolded. We accomplish this by toggling the classNames, the cold is straightforward

```
            toggleFoldedState = ->
                content.css 'color','red'

                if content.hasClass 'auto-folded--folded'
                    content.removeClass('auto-folded--folded').addClass('auto-folded--unfolded')
                else if content.hasClass 'auto-folded--unfolded'
                    content.removeClass('auto-folded--unfolded').addClass('auto-folded--folded')

                return
```

and we use `ng-click="toggleFoldedState()"` to bind this action to the toggling button

We have to do some initial work to fold the text if it's tall enough at page loaded. However, `link` function of directive is to create the actual Dom, before dom rendering.So in `link`, we cannot know the height, that's why we register the `init()` to `ngcontentloaded` event:

```
            init = ()->
                contentHeight = content.outerHeight()
                if contentHeight > 48
                    content.addClass 'auto-folded--folded'
                content.show()

            $$window.on 'ngcontentloaded',init
```

here I use 48px as 3-line-height, you can define your own, or calculate dynamically from the dom, like `content.css('lineHeight')`.

since this is done after dom rendering, so the text is already displayed before init(). There will be a ugly slideUp effect. That's why we first hide the dom using css(as following), and `content.show()` in init

So we are done with directive, the folded/unfoled state are controlled by className. here we go.

## css.sass

(sorry I wrote it in `sass`)

```
.auto-folded
    display: none  //only display after init()
    position: relative

    .auto-folded--more //the button is placed at right-bottom, and default to hidden
        display: none
        position: absolute
        right: 0
        bottom: 0

    &.auto-folded--folded //when folded, set maxHeight, and overflow to hidden
        max-height: 48px
        overflow: hidden
        .auto-folded--more // toggling button is displayed,
            display: block
            &:before // and it's text is "more"
                content: "more"

    &.auto-folded--unfolded //when unfoled, s
        .auto-folded--more  // toggling button is displayed
            display: block
            &:before // and it's text is "hide"
                content: "hide"
```

So the text of toggling button and visibility of it , are all controlled by the class of its parent.

for the parent
1. if text is not 3-line height, it will only have `'auto-folded'` as css class, so the button is hidden

2. if text is over 3-line height, in `init()` process, it's classNames will be `'auto-folded auto-folded--folded'`.
   then the button is shown. clicking it will toggle parent's classNames between `'auto-folded--folded'` and `'auto-folded--unfolded'`

Comment: Actually me just trying few things but cant write something in angular. I can do this in jquery quickly but not in angular. any example will help me lot.thanks

Comment: @KrishnaBhatt code is attached. Tested it and it worked, but I'm not familiar with jsfiddle, so it may be not that straightforward~

Comment: Unfortunately your fiddle seems to be empty.  You're using jquery in this as well for addClass/etc, right?