# Create read more/less toggle using directive in AngularJs.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have few lines of description on my page. On the page loads I want to show only 150 characters with a link Read More on click of which I want to show the rest of the description and Read Less link. In fact I want to toggle between Read More/Less. I want do this by creating a directive not by using limitTo filter provided by AngularJs. I have gone through the link **[Create read more link in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400408/create-read-more-link-in-angularjs)** but it did not help me. I don't have code example or jsfiddle because I don't know how to start, I am new to AngularJs. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had great success wrapping [jQuery dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) with a simple Angular directive. I can't drop in the exact code, but the core of the directive:

- Is an `A` (attribute) directive
- Requires `ngBindHtml`
- Has a link function:

  - Where a `$scope.truncated` variable is set to keep track of whether `dotdotdot` has been applied
  - That watches `element.html()` for changes, and if it changes and `dotdotdot` has not been applied, applies it by calling `element.dotdotdot()` and flips the `truncated` flag