# how to remove the html tags which are getting with the read more button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, text-analysis

I have some text to display and after reaching 500 characters ,should display read more button.when i click on read more text should expand.But here the problem is when i copy the text and paste it on my text area it should displaying read more button.
Attaching screen .[image]

Comment: Checkout this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21400408/create-read-more-link-in-angularjs

Comment: @AvneshShakya getting for normal text.

Comment: You can make it on text length or better create a directive and toggle button.

Comment: @AvneshShakya Yes. I am using text length for this am using angular filter.when it reaches the condition the toggle should show.

Comment: so what problem you are facing now?

Comment: @AvneshShakya when i copy and paste the text from other websites.for example the following text:   TVF releases new video 'Aitihasik Qtiyapa'..... The Viral Fever (TVF) has released a new video 'Aitihasik Qtiyapa', which is part of the '#FakeOff' challenge in the 'Comedy Konkout', a digital comedy competition for comedy groups and stand-up comedians. TVF's video focuses on two workers who constructed the Taj Mahal and their conversation while waiting for their payment, which​ turns out to be different from their expectations.

Comment: @AvneshShakya  when it contains url or link EX:URL: https://www.inshorts.com/en/news/tvf-releases-new-video-aitihasik-qtiyapa-1467648896020

Comment: try `ng-change="checkText(newValue)"` in your `text-area`, so once text change do accordingly.

Comment: what can i use in place of newValue . if i directly use same thing it's not working.@AvneshShakya

Comment: check this: http://jsfiddle.net/pKBVu/3/ it can help you

Comment: @AvneshShakya.When displaying the text i am facing the issue.Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131506/discussion-between-avnesh-shakya-and-shiva).